# MySQLi query in while loop not adding to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, while-loop

I have got the following code to add a user's orders to a database. The orders are stored as an array ($row), which are then set to single variables in the while loop, which are then set as the query. No error message is displayed, but the records are not added to the MySQL database. I have put the area I think is the problem in bold. I have looked at several other help threads and tried them, but they won't work for this.

I'm fairly new to PHP, so please can you try to keep answers in plain English where possible.
Thanks if anyone can give me a hand with this.

```
<?php

session_start();
?>


<?php



//db connect

require('connect_db.php');

//define variables

$id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$fn=$_SESSION['first_name'];
$ln=$_SESSION['last_name'];
$bank=$_POST['bank'];
$ano=$_POST['account'];
$sort=$_POST['sort_code'];

//get order details
**$qa="SELECT total, product, quantity, FROM orders WHERE user_id='$id'";

$ra=mysqli_query($dbc, $qa);



while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
//insert to table
$product=$row['product'];
$quantity=$row['quantity'];
$total=$row['total'];
$qb="INSERT INTO order_contents(user_id, first_name, last_name, product, quantity, price, bank, account_no, sort_code) VALUES '$id', '$fn', '$ln', '$product', '$quantity', '$total', SHA1('$bank'), SHA1('$ano'), SHA1('$sort'))";

mysqli_query($dbc, $qb) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
}**



//clear db

mysqli_query($dbc, "DELETE FROM orders WHERE user_id='$user_id'");


//mysql close

mysqli_close($dbc);


//redirect to thank you page

header("Location:http://emsworthsailspares.net23.net/thanks.php");


?>



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You dont need the open/close php tags twice. Just do <?php in the beginning of your PHP and ?> at the end

Comment: You have a typo.  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) should be $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ra, MYSQLI_ASSOC) )

Comment: Thanks for this. Have made the changes, and will be useful in the future, but it hasn't solved the issue

Comment: Thanks Dave. Seems like I've got two things going wrong, as it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that your query at $qa is returning results, and that the while() loop is doing something?  Do echo the contents of $qb.  Does the resulting query run if you use it directly in MySQL?

Comment: Comment out the `header("Location` line so you can see your errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off with a single [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) query, reducing the need to round-trip everything through the client:

```
INSERT INTO order_contents (user_id, first_name, last_name, product, quantity, price, bank,
    account_no, sort_code)
SELECT '$id', '$fn', '$ln', product, quantity, total, SHA1('$bank'), SHA1('$ano'), SHA1('$sort')
FROM orders
WHERE user_id=$id
```

Note the mixture of dynamic and 'fixed' field types in the select portion of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You put the query into $ra, then attempt to use $r

```
$ra=mysqli_query($dbc, $qa);



while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ra, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Answer (score 0):

> while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))

You should change the $r to $ra like your code above.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ra, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```